# Why is the use of udelay() in a Linux driver unreliable?

Tags: linux, driver, scheduler

My understanding is that udelay() does not prevent the scheduler from assigning the CPU to higher priority tasks in a situation of stress.

I think, though, that my knowledge of the true causes is somewhat shallow, and would appreciate some deeper insight on this.

Comment: Where is it said that udelay does not prevent the scheduler from assigning the CPU to higher priority tasks in a situation of stress ?

Answer (score 1):

See [delays - Information on the various kernel delay / sleep mechanisms](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt).

There is no talking of `udelay()` being unreliable, quite the contrary it is the recommended way in atomic context as well as for sleeping for *a few* microseconds in non-atomic context.

While you are right saying *that udelay() does not prevent the scheduler from assigning the CPU to higher priority tasks in a situation of stress*, it creates such stress itself by busy-waiting instead of yielding the CPU to other (maybe equal priority) tasks from the start, which is why it is not recommended for longer delays.

Comment: Where is it documented that "udelay does not prevent the scheduler from assigning the CPU to higher priority tasks in a situation of stress" ? Thx

Comment: @ransh - It is documented for example in the document linked above by use of the term NON-ATOMIC CONTEXT - execution can be interrupted (possibly modifying the state of the current task).

Comment: Can is be used in atomic context, although can be interrupted ?

Comment: @ransh - Sure, it can, because it's not `udelay()`'s job, but the job of the code which sets up the atomic context, to prevent interruptions. `udelay()` doing that would not help, because interruptions could still occur prior to its call or after its return.